# Atmega2560V, trying to burn bootloaders of MegaCore

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, arduino-ide, bootloader

I am trying to burn MegaCore bootloaders to it, I have setup my custom PCB  with Atmega2560V-8AU and 8Mhz Crystal + Load Caps all assembled on using PCBA process.
I am trying to burn MegaCore bootlaoders to it, I am using Arduino UNO as ISP Programmer. My connections are all correct, It shows different Device Signatures (see below) whenever I hit Burn Bootloaders....

> 0x0000ff
>   0x00003f
>   0x0000ff
>   0x00ff00
>   0x001000
>   0xff0000
>   0xfc0000
>   0x00fe00

This is complete output with different Device Signatures

> Arduino: 1.8.3 (Windows 10), Board: "ATmega2560, Arduino MEGA pinout,
>   2.7v, Disabled (default), 8 MHz external"
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avrdude
>   -CC:\Users\mudas\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\hardware\MegaCore-avr-100-pin\avr/avrdude.conf
>   -v -patmega2560 -cstk500v1 -PCOM4 -b19200 -e -Ulock:w:0x3f:m -Uefuse:w:0xfd:m -Uhfuse:w:0xd6:m -Ulfuse:w:0xf7:m
>
> avrdude: Version 6.3, compiled on Jan 17 2017 at 12:00:53
>            Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
>            Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch
>
> ```
>      System wide configuration file is "C:\Users\mudas\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\hardware\MegaCore-avr-100-pin\avr/avrdude.conf"
>
>      Using Port                    : COM4
>      Using Programmer              : stk500v1
>      Overriding Baud Rate          : 19200
>      AVR Part                      : ATmega2560
>      Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
>      PAGEL                         : PD7
>      BS2                           : PA0
>      RESET disposition             : dedicated
>      RETRY pulse                   : SCK
>      serial program mode           : yes
>      parallel program mode         : yes
>      Timeout                       : 200
>      StabDelay                     : 100
>      CmdexeDelay                   : 25
>      SyncLoops                     : 32
>      ByteDelay                     : 0
>      PollIndex                     : 3
>      PollValue                     : 0x53
>      Memory Detail                 :
>
>                               Block Poll               Page                       Polled
>        Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
>        ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
>        eeprom        65    10     8    0 no       4096    8      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
>        flash         65    10   256    0 yes    262144  256   1024  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
>        lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
>        hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
>        efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
>        lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
>        calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
>        signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
>
>      Programmer Type : STK500
>      Description     : Atmel STK500 Version 1.x firmware
>      Hardware Version: 2
>      Firmware Version: 1.18
>      Topcard         : Unknown
>      Vtarget         : 0.0 V
>      Varef           : 0.0 V
>      Oscillator      : Off
>      SCK period      : 0.1 us
> ```
>
> avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions
>
> Error while burning bootloader. Reading |
>
> ############################################ | 100% 0.02s
>
> avrdude: Device signature = 0x00fe00 avrdude: Expected signature for
>   ATmega2560 is 1E 98 01
>            Double check chip, or use -F to override this check.
>
> avrdude done.  Thank you.

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
What should be the problem.??? How to solve this.?

Comment: Also posted at:https://github.com/MCUdude/MegaCore/issues/63 and http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=494076

Comment: Yes and also at http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/atmega2560v-trying-burn-bootloaders-megacore

Comment: Now that the problem has been solved, would you mind taking the time to answer your question so that it might help others? From the [GitHub issue report](https://github.com/MCUdude/MegaCore/issues/63), I know that once you were able to start reading a consistent (though incorrect) device signature the final step was to use the `-F` AVRDUDE option to override the signature check but it's not clear what the change was that you made to get from the inconsistent device signature readings to the consistent readings. I believe it was a hardware change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed 8Mhz from board and followed this instructions [LINK](http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/tutsoft-recovering-locked-out-avr), and burnt bootloaders using -F override check, then i returned 8Mhz oscillator to Atmega2560V and see device signature and it's automatically appears 0x1e9801 rather than 0x1e9803

Comment: Is this an answer or comment?

Comment: This is an answer.

Comment: Please, accept your own answer to close this question.